# Is the theory of Boolean algebras equal to the theory of Boole's algebra?

Tags: logic, model-theory, boolean-algebra

Let $BA$ be the set of axioms of Boolean algebras.

Let $Th(BA)$ be the set of first-order sentences that are true when conjoined with the axioms in $BA$.

I believe that $Th(BA) = Th(\langle \{0,1\}, \land, \lor, \lnot \rangle)$ where $\land, \lor,\lnot$ are the usual propositional operations interpreted over $\{0,1\}$.

Is this result true?

Comment: Regarding the last paragraph, let me point out that $\forall x. x\lor x\leftrightarrow x$ is not a sentence of first-order logic in the language of Boolean algebras. Every atomic formula in this language has the form $t = t'$, where $t$ and $t'$ are terms, so every sentence must contain at least one equals sign!

Comment: Also, your second sentence doesn't actually make sense as written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **false**. For example, the sentence $$\forall x,y,z(x=y\vee x=z\vee y=z)$$ is true in the two-element Boolean algebra but false in others.

A less-trivial example: any *finite* Boolean algebra satisfies the sentence "There is an atom" ($\exists x,y\forall z[x<y\wedge \neg (x<z\wedge z<y)]$) but there are infinite atomless Boolean algebras.

That said, if we restrict attention to *equational* properties - equational logic being the small fragment of first-order logic consisting of the universal closures of atomic formulas - then we get an affirmative answer, since every Boolean algebra is a quotient of a subalgebra of a power of the $2$-element B.A. and each of those operations on structures preserves equational properties. (The converse of this is deeper but still true - see "HSP theorem.")

Comment: thanks for your answer. by the converse you mean that the two sets coincide only for a universal prefix?

Comment: @user1868607 No, I mean the converse of "each of those operations on structures preserves equational properties" - if $\mathcal{A}$ has the same equational theory as $\mathcal{B}$ (or a proper superset of that theory - remember, there's no negation in equational logic), then $\mathcal{A}$ is a quotient of a substructure of a power of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: Not only equations but also conditional equations (Horn sentences). Any (strict) Horn sentence which holdsin the $2$-element Boolean algebra holds in all Boolean algebras.

Comment: @user14111 True, I didn't mean to imply optimality!